# How to test chains of methods in rspec. Delay is one of them

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am trying to write a test like this:

```
  it 'logs events' do
        expect(Event).to receive("delay.create!").with(hash_including(
                                                    app_context: app_context,
                                                    event_type: Event::EventType::FOOD_SUBSCRIPTION_STARTED))
        subject
      end
```

for code that looks like this:

```
Event.delay.create!(
      event_type: event_type,
      description: 'Automatically populated',
      date: Time.now.utc,
      eventable: user,
      app_context: app_context
    )
```

I want to just test that at some point, Event is called with .delay and .create and that the hash passed to create contains 2 key-value pairs. How do I do this?

Event.delay just returns a long string of numbers and letters so I don't think I want to stub that?

Comment: I think you're looking for `receive_message_chain`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of ways.

One way (which works if the first call is not big and messy) is just to stub the second call eg:

```
expect(Event.delay).to receive(:create).with(...).and_return(...)
```

The other way is to create a stub for the first call and use it in the second eg:

```
delay_stub = double
expect(delay_stub).to receive(:create).with(...).and_return(...)
expect(Event).to receive(:delay).with(...).and_return(delay_stub)
```

Note that in my experience you have to do the above in the order given for it to work best.

Comment: I didn't know you could do expect(Event.delay). Also you're using 'expect' there. Should you write: allow(Event.delay).to receive(:create)and_return(Event) or something?

Comment: `expect` sets up an expectation just like `expect(2+2).to eq(4)` - you will use it when you are actually trying to make certain that this method gets called (as described in your `it "logs events"` spec given in your original post).  `allow` is the other option, and you use it for when you are testing something else, but you want to not run the create method, but just paper over it and make sure it returns a result you want. You'll most often use this in context-blocks for other specs.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually wrote a test like this (turns out the problem was also that

```
 Event.delay.create!
```

was being called twice in the test with different arguments so I needed to use "ordered" as well.

```
  it 'logs events' do
        allow(Event).to receive(:delay).and_return(Event)
        expect(Event).to receive(:create!).with(hash_including(
          app_context: app_context,
          event_type: Event::EventType::FOOD_SUBSCRIPTION_STARTED)).ordered
        expect(Event).to receive(:create!).with(hash_including(
          app_context: app_context,
          event_type: Event::EventType::FOOD_SUBSCRIPTION_COMPLETED)).ordered
        subject
      end
```